Performance between Laravel Scheduler vs Crontab
I've always used the Linux Crontab to call my cronjobs. Most of the times I only had 5 to 10 cronjobs, which is pretty manageable, specially in terms of UI. I also used many times the cPanel cronjobs interface, which is basically a mask of Linux Crontab.
I'm now facing with a project that has roughly 20 cronjobs (and can grow) that must be executed through different times of the day. I'm managing all of this cronjobs via cPanel. Things can get a little bit messy, specially because I'm not allowed to move up-and-down the cronjobs already created.
I was wondering, how bad, performance wise, would be to handle all cronjobs with Laravel Scheduler compared to Crontab?
From my understanding:

Using cPanel / Crontab delegates the operation of handling the cronjob to the Operating System, meaning my application is never hit with any request if there is no cronjob to be executed
Using Laravel Scheduler my application is hit every minute, whether has or not cronjobs to be executed

